# Angular 6: How to convert Observable[anyobject] to ReplaySubject

Tags: rxjs, angular6, rxjs6

I'm using Angular 6: I have a service httppost with return type `Observable<IResourceInfo>`.

```
searchResourceSuggestion(param: ISearchResourceParam): Observable<IResourceInfo[]>{
return this.httpClient.post<IResourceInfo[]>(url, param); }
```

And in my component file: 
I call it in event :

```
this.searchResourceService.searchResourceSuggestion(param).pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy)).subscribe(data => {
this.data= data;});
```

But `this.data` is `ReplaySubject<IResourceInfo[]> = new ReplaySubject<IResourceInfo[]>(1);`
and it show error missing the following properties from type ReplaySubject.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: not clear what is wrong and what you want to do(in a deeper sense). `this.data` should be IResourceInfo[] such as `data` IS `IResourceInfo[]`. It is "unboxed" observable. tell why you want replay subject in first place

Comment: if you need as ReplaySubject - just to this: `this.data.next(data)`, and not reassign